# Discord.JS | Getting channel object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I have some issues understanding the Discord.JS module, I have no clue of how to connect my bot to a server, even after looking at a lot of documentaries!

```
var Discord = require           ( 'discord.js' ),
    Client = new Discord.Client (              );

Client.on ( 'ready', () => {
  console.log ( Client.channels.get ( '***ChannelID***' ) );
});

Client.login ( '***TOKEN***' );
```

**Output**:

```
undefined
```

Where getting the channel returns `undefined` even I pass the correct id.

I don't know if the bot can connect to it without being invited to the server, and can't seem to find anything on it either?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bots must be in a server to get an ID

Example (Sorry my bot is in python but it is similar in the way it uses API):

[image: Example]

This is because my bot is in the second channel but the first is made up