# Discord Webhooks Channel returns undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, webhooks, channel

I'm new to using webhooks and I've pored over the discord documentation to help set me up with a very basic bot. At this point all I want to do is for the bot to come online and use a webhook to make a post. I've even directly copied the basic code from The Discord Webhooks documentation and I cant get that to work.

Using some console logs I've determined that client.channels.cache.get(config.webhookID); returns undefined and therefore channel.fetchWebhooks() is not a function. Is this still the way to get webhooks that are in the channel or is the documentation behind?

I'm turning to any experienced user that could potentially help me with this problem. I would really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Some Title')
    .setColor('#0099ff');

client.once('ready', async () => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(config.webhookID); //This is the problem.
    try {
        const webhooks = await channel.fetchWebhooks(); //This will not execute because channel is undefined.
        const webhook = webhooks.first();

        await webhook.send('Webhook test', {
            username: 'some-username',
            avatarURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png',
            embeds: [embed],
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error trying to send: ', error);
    }
});

client.login(config.token);
```

The error in the console is this:

```
Error trying to send:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchWebhooks' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:13:34)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:433:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:417:10)    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:199:14)       
    at WebSocketShard.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at WebSocketShard.checkReady (C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:467:12)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:439:16)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
```

Comment: Is `config.webhookID` valid? Did you check it??

Comment: @Saeed, I believe so. I will make a new webhook after this is solved so I can post this here. I am using the "703706406125174825" part of the link. https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/703706406125174825/xanVKdIbiNo7KiD2jNPlPy1Aiq5wmdG1BUn4IzRvBx_vcSNlpN645hFx-j52pzEWcZUO

Comment: Remove `cache` and get it with `client.channels.get`

Comment: @Saeed that is not a function. I believe cache.get() was added in discord.js v12

Comment: And did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321485/discord-js-getting-channel-object-returns-undefined) question?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. I was using the field "id" when I should have been using the field "channel_id".